# How to create a new layer with specific data from a large data base of irrelevant data?

Tags: qgis, duplication

I am a complete beginner to QGIS. I am trying to isolate an individual set of data from a very large data base to plot in another layer. I have isolated the piece of data by using the `Selection by expression` and entering the value I want. however, I am unable to duplicate that layer to just have the selected single data point I want in it. Does anyone know how to solve this basic issue for a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your desired data is selected. Then right click the layer in the layer window and choose `save as`. In the new window, make sure you tick the box "save only selected features".

Note: For this to work properly it is recommended, that your data is saved as a shapefile in the first place.